# Show Dialog without clipping outside a form

Tags: vb.net, dialog, cursor

How can I show a dialog on mouse point without clipping the dialog itself outside?

For example, when I r-click a control that is near the right edge of the screen, the dialog will appear on the left side and if the control is near below the screen it will show the dialog up of the cursor.

This is my code:

```
If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
       Dim tool = New Form2 With {
           .Location = New Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y),
           .WhoSend = sender 'some property
       }
       tool.ShowDialog()
End If
```

This will always show the dialog on the bottom-right of the cursor even if the dialog is clipping outside the window.

Comment: Pictures would help here. Expected vs actual

Comment: This is the kind of thing that ContextMenu/Strip does.  It has the code to ensure that it is moved if necessary to keep the menu completely on the screen.  Also the kind of class you'd use on a right-click.  Form does not have that code, you must add it yourself.  Be sure to do so by subscribing the Load event so it still works correctly when the form rescales.  The Screen class gives you the bounds.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried the `ContextMenuStrip`. How can I get the control where I click it in after clicking an item inside the `ContextMenuStrip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `My.Computer.Screen.Bounds` to get the area of the screen and set the location according to it, and then relocate your form position.

```
If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
   Dim ScreenBounds = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds

   Dim tool = New Form2 With {
       .Location = New Point(if( Cursor.Position.X + .Width > ScreenBounds.Width,ScreenBounds.Width - .Width ,Cursor.Position.X ),
                             if( Cursor.Position.Y + .Height > ScreenBounds.Width,ScreenBounds.Height - .Height ,Cursor.Position.Y ),
       .WhoSend = sender 'some property
   }
   tool.ShowDialog()
End If
```

Comment: Yep, That's also what I think, just a tiny difference of your code      

`If Cursor.Position.X + tool.Width > Width Or Cursor.Position.Y + tool.Height > Height Then
                tool.Location = New Point(Cursor.Position.X - tool.Width, Cursor.Position.Y - tool.Height)
            Else
                tool.Location = New Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)
            End If`  

Mine is based on form size, which is irrelevant because the main form is in fullscreen

Comment: Keep in mind that you might face some problems when running the application on a computer with 2 monitors. As @Hans Passant stated, it would be better to use something like a `ContextMenuStrip` for such a feature, since it already has all threatments done.

Comment: Right, it is not correct code.  Use Screen.FromRectangle() to find the correct monitor.  And it is really, really important to do this with the Load event of the form so you know the actual size of the form.  Code today needs to be dpiAware.